# Ответственность и DRY, KISS

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, solid

Пишу преимущественно на `.NET(Core, Xamarin)`. Сейчас работаю над проектом с фронтом на `React JS`(фронт тоже я пишу), и словил себя на мысли, что много повторяю код похожий друг на друга, то есть нарушаю `DRY`.
И казалось бы нет проблемы вынести всё похожее куда то в одно место, разнести по dependency сервисам и т.п., но я боюсь последствий в лице принципа единственной ответственности в случае расширения функциональности.

И так вопрос, банально, я создаю методы по работе например с контроллером пользователя:

1. `Index` - лист юзеров
2. `Create` - создаем
3. `Edit` - редактируем

Для `edit` и `create` я создаю отдельные как `action` так и `view` компоненты реакта, которые достаточно похожи друг на друга, отличия минимальны, не большая разница в наличии данных(`id, active, etc`) `viewmodel` и набором методов по манипуляциям с БД. Дополнительно я создаю для индекса например `UsersViewModel` и для `edit\create` общую `UserViewModel`.

Правильно ли я делаю или стоит использовать один `action` и один `view` с ветвлениями?

Под ветвлениями я подразумеваю ряд проверок на предмет что сейчас происходит `create\edit`. Тоже самое и на `view`, один компонент для всего. Но это по мимо ответственности может еще и нарушать `KISS(Keep it simple, stupid)`.

**Поделитесь опытом.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь возникает вопрос, а какие варианты решения возникших вопросов вы видите. Если есть сомнения в правильности, значит должно быть представление альтернативного решения.

**DRY** - решается декомпозицией операции до такой степени, чтобы ее части могли участвовать в разных операциях.

**KISS** - пока у вас не пухнет голова от стараний уместить в себе знания о том, что где валяется, то всё нормально. Ну и плюс здесь может быть воздержание от вкручивания модных штук тогда, когда от них кода много и толку мало. Например, я не вкручиваю IoC контейнер в минипроекты на 1,5 VM и 2,5 View, это и есть KISS.

**SRP** - когда вам задают вопрос "что делает этот класс/метод/библиотека?", если вы можете кратко ответить без перечислений списков возможностей, то SRP соблюдается. Например "этот метод складывает 2 числа", "этот класс работает с API через HTTP", "эта библиотека содержит полезные MVVM примочки".

Ну и не стоит забывать про остальне SOLID-составляющие, они в совокупности с используемыми шаблонами проектирования должны дать понимание, куда двигаться, приращивая к проекту всё больше и больше новых штук.

Если у вас есть коллекция чего-то, и вы для нее реализуете какой-то CRUD, это вполне может быть реализовано в рамках одного класса. А внешние интеграции типа HTTP-API можно вкрутить в него через зависимости (DI). Это не должно быть сложно.

Comment: Мое представление решения мне не нравится. Для меня выглядит плохо когда в одном методе решается 2 задачи создания или редактирования объекта. В случае расширения логики/функционала этот метод разростается и обрастает обфускацией. Нет с кем обсудить, я одиночка. Я ждал вашего ответа :)

Comment: Например у меня есть масса контроллеров с одинаковым набором методов Index, Edit, Create и т.д. разница в вычетке. Меняются модели которые вычитываются из БД но в целом функциональная одинаковая и меня начинает посещать мысль начать строить костыли что бы все это свести в одну большую не читаемую кучу кода

Comment: @Winteriscoming натяните на них общий интерфейс, можно будет на абстракциях упростить работу с ними, и т.д.

Comment: @Winteriscoming _Мое представление решения мне не нравится._ - если и после этого сомнения остались, пересильте себя, создайте форк проекта и реализуйте в нём то, что представили, а затем сравните с исходным. Уверен, вопрос решится.